# DiagnosticsProperty<BoxConstraints>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, sized-box, debug-console

Please I am having this error in my flutter code. Below is my code:

return Scaffold(

```
    appBar: AppBar(

      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
      title: const Text('Categories'),
    ),
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      transformAlignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text(
                    "Option1",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                Container(height: 2, color: Colors.white),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text(
                    "Option2",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                Container(height: 2, color: Colors.white),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text(
                    "Option3",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                Container(height: 2, color: Colors.white),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text(
                    "Option4",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                  title: const Text('pick color'),
                                  content: SingleChildScrollView(
                                      child: ColorPicker(
                                    pickerColor: pickerColor,
                                    onColorChanged: changeColor,
                                  )),
                                  actions: [
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                      child: const Text("You gerrit now"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() =>
                                            currentColor = pickerColor);
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      },
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ));
                      },
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "colorpicker",
                    ),
                    const Text("stuff",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

Also, below is the error in my debug console pointing at the point of code flaw:

if (!constraints.hasBoundedHeight) {

```
      RenderBox node = this;
      while (
          !node.constraints.hasBoundedHeight && node.parent is RenderBox) {
        node = node.parent! as RenderBox;
      }

      information.add(node.describeForError(
          'The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is'));
    }
    throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
      ...information,
      DiagnosticsProperty<BoxConstraints>(
          'The constraints that applied to the $runtimeType were',
          constraints,
          style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty),
      DiagnosticsProperty<Size>('The exact size it was given was', _size,
          style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty),
      ErrorHint(
          'See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.'),
    ]);
  }
```

I think it is coming from the listview and I have tried every edit possible, even with online resources, I still end up with the same error.
I changed the container (initially wrapped around the ListView) into sizedBox, and I also set shrinkwrap to true and added the physics key and value too but nothing got better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height of `sizebox` for the `ListTile`:

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `child` on GestureDetector. Also there are some tweaks you can make like using scaffold `backgroundColor`.

Here is a simple structure

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
          title: const Text('Categories'),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text(
                      "Option1",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                  Container(height: 2, color: Colors.white),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text(
                      "Option2",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                  Container(height: 2, color: Colors.white),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text(
                      "Option3",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                  Container(height: 2, color: Colors.white),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text(
                      "Option4",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: const Text(
                      "colorpicker",
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text("stuff",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.green)),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```